# why the Webcan does not work with ubuntu in websites?

Tags: 14.04

Why it does not work the camera with ubuntu on websites like chatroulette, facebookvideocall and hangouts?

Is there any solution to this problem?

I appreciate your answers!

Comment: I had the same problem , but it worked fine after updating my system from software updater.